# Calculations on columns (column by column) in Dataset

Tags: dataset

Dataset from doc:

```
dataset = Dataset[{
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x" |>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y" |>,
   <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z" |>,
   <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x" |>,
   <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y" |>,
   <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z" |>}]
```

There is a built-in way to Divide all column by constant, i.e. 2:

```
dataset[Divide[#, 2] &, "a"]
```

If I want to Divide all values of "a" to corresponding values of "b" the naive way is as follows:

```
Normal[dataset[All, "a"]] / Normal[dataset[All, "b"]]
```

What are more natural ways to make such calculations, say, Division, between columns in Dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Normal @ dataset[All, #a / #b&]
```

> {1/("x"), 2/("y"), 3/("z"), 4/("x"), 5/("y"), 6/("z")}

Also:

```
Normal @ dataset[All, Apply[Divide]]
Normal[Divide @@@ dataset] 
Normal[Query[All, Divide @@ # &]@dataset]
```